# Stop text from overlapping html and css

Tags: html, css

when I resize my window my text is overlapping. How do I stop this from happening? I want it to just resize if it colliding with the other text elements or, if not possible, that they just stack under each other?
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f6Dp.png)

I already tried

- flex box
- set min height

and can someone tell me what position I should use mainly?

```css
.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 550px;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(41, 80, 143);
  border: 5px solid rgb(46, 84, 149);
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.tekst {
  color: white;
  position: static;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.ccontroller {
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.creator1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.creator2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.aboutus {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  background-color: #123456;
  height: 15px;
  width: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #123456;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  min-width: 550px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  min-width: 550px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex_container">
    <div class="bar">
      <h1 class="tekst" title="Coffeesnakes">Coffeesnakes</h1>
      <button class="aboutus" onclick="func()">About us!</button>
      <div class="ccontroller">
        <p class="creator1" title="Can code: Java, c#, html, js, python, arduino">Christian2B</p>
        <p class="creator2" title="Can code: html, python, js ">Timgb11</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is a `forb` element?

Comment: i removed it , I din't know why it was there

Comment: When you say the text is overlapping to what do you refer particularly?

Comment: when I scale down the size of the windows there is nota nought space anymore so it is overlapping . I just added an ss to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `button` has a `.aboutus` class which sets `position:absolute;`. This ignores the width of the other elements and absolute positions the element in the parent div.
**Please provide an actual representation of what you are trying to achieve.**

If you want a structured approach, you can do something like this with flexbox (resize the windows to see how it goes):

```css
.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 550px;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(41, 80, 143);
  border: 5px solid rgb(46, 84, 149);
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tekst {
  color: white;
  position: static;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.ccontroller {
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.creator1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.creator2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.aboutus {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #123456;
  width: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #123456;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  min-width: 550px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  min-width: 550px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex_container">
    <div class="bar">
      <p class="creator1" title="Can code: Java, c#, html, js, python, arduino">Christian2B</p>
      <h1 class="tekst" title="Coffeesnakes">Coffeesnakes</h1>
      <p class="creator2" title="Can code: html, python, js ">Timgb11</p>
      <button class="aboutus" onclick="func()">About us!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: its now stack next to each other , but now the page is getting bigger, so I need to scroll to the right to see the other thing , can it also just fit int the page?

Comment: oh wait never mind it doen't anymore

Comment: @Christian2B I would suggest you to review the code, as it can be improved a lot. I removed many 'unnecessary' things, but there is room for more.

Comment: I know, I was just trying to fix it myself so , but every time a thing din't work. I din't remove it

Answer (score 0):

A way to fix your problem is using flex box, but this time add a part in the css where once the screen gets to a certain size, the flex-box goes from row, to column. Like this:

```
.bar-element {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

@media (max-width:700px){
    .bar-element {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

SO once the screen gets to a curtain size it changes the layout.

Here is a demo:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
}

@media (max-width:700px){
   .flex {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

You can also check out the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264679/how-to-change-css-when-the-screen-size-changes), to learn more on how to change properties on different screen sizes.

Here is your code edited:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    /* .flex_container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        min-width: 550px;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;
    } */
    
    .bar {
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgb(41, 80, 143);
        border: 5px solid rgb(46, 84, 149);
        height: 30px;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .tekst {
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .ccontroller {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: fit-content;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        justify-self: flex-end;
    }
    
    .creator1 {
        display: block;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: auto;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .creator2 {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: auto;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .aboutus {
        display: block;
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: white;
        background-color: #123456;
        height: fit-content;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 16px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    body {
        background-color: #123456;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        min-width: 550px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:700px) {
        .bar {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .ccontroller {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="flex_container">
        <div class="bar">
            <h1 class="tekst" title="Coffeesnakes">Coffeesnakes</h1>
            <button class="aboutus" onclick="func()">About us!</button>
            <div class="ccontroller">
                <p class="creator1" title="Can code: Java, c#, html, js, python, arduino">Christian2B</p>
                <p class="creator2" title="Can code: html, python, js ">Timgb11</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For it to work you are going to have to run it on full screen though. So click the "Full page", and it will put it in full screen, then when you make the screen size small, it will change position.

Comment: it did something , but not what it was supposed to
image: https://imgur.com/a/6SfVZwP
this is the same on full screen

Comment: The image link doesn't work.

Comment: Ok i edited your code, and I think it should work now.

Comment: I did have to delete some code, and make changes, so that it would work.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working! Check out my GIt repo: https://github.com/LublubXT/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241484/discussion-between-lublubxt-and-christian2b).

Answer (score 0):

Add `min-width`to you items. Like in the abstract working example below:

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  min-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
  <p>baz</p>
</div>
```